# hexapdf gem make text ordered list rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to generate pdf with hexapdf gem

I want to have nice inline ordered list.

This is what i do

```rb
note = "1. Sub text 1: \n \tsub text 2"
note_text = HexaPDF::Layout::TextFragment.create(
  note,
  font: pdf.document.fonts.add("Helvetica", variant: :bold),
  font_size: 9
)
tl.fit([note_text], 470, 100).draw(canvas, 0, y - 1)
```

it generate text like this below

[image: generated text]

the problem is text 'sub text 2' is not inline with text 'sub text 1'.

**I want have text 'sub text 2' start inline with the start of text 'Sub text 1' (after '1. ')**

how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems it does not print the tabulation correctly, but anyway, it's not going to produce a 100% correct result.

To correctly align "Sub text 1" with "sub text 2", you have to create another text fragment, which you place next to a text fragment with your "1."

In other word: you create a text fragment for your paragraph, and naturally, lines will all start at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `\t` doesn't work. This is a quick hack - how about adding 3-4 spaces before `sub text 2`?

I tried it in IRB and it works as follows:

```
irb(main):003:0> puts "1. Sub text 1: \n   sub text 2"
1. Sub text 1: 
   sub text 2
```

However, since Helvetica isn't a mono font, you'd need to play around with how many spaces would "fake" the appearance of the document being formatted.

Otherwise there might be a gem that handles more advanced text/document formatting.